# How to search an array in Jquery like SQL LIKE value% statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have an array with some values. How can I search that array using jQuery for a value which is matched or close to it?

```
var a = ["foo","fool","cool","god","acl"];
```

If I want to search for `c`, then it should return `cool` but not `acl`.

How I can achieve that?

Comment: How is `c` close to `cool` but not to `acl` ? Do you want the word to start with `c` ?

Comment: You can use regex as replacement for `value%` using `/^value.*/`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
arr = jQuery.grep(a, function (value) {
    search = /c/gi;
    if(value.match(search)) return true;
        return false;
    });
```

or

```
function find(arr) {
    var result = [];

    for (var i in arr) {
        if (arr[i].match(/c/)) {
            result.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

window.onload = function() {
    console.log(find(["foo","fool","cool","god","acl"]));
};
```

Comment: -1: jQuery? Where from?

Comment: @Jon: jQuery is right in the question title. And the question body. I've updated the tags.

Comment: Oh, right. Only looked at the tags, sorry.

Comment: Better `return !!value.match(search)`

Comment: @jcubic:- Yes I agree but I think OP can modify this as per his/her need. This answer will give him/her enough hint!!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to check if each string in the array begins with the string you are searching for:

```
var strings = [ "foo", "cool", "acl" ];
var needle = "c";

for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; ++i) {
    if (strings[i].substring(0, needle.length) === needle) {
        alert("found: " + strings[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it is to check for words starting with 'c' and iterate of the array.

```
var ar = ['acl','cool','cat']
for(var i = 0 ; i<ar.length ; i++){
   console.log(ar[i].match(/^c/))
}
//Prints:
//null
//["c", index: 0, input: "cool"]
//["c", index: 0, input: "cat"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter method which is available since JavaScript 1.6. It will give you back an array with the filtered values. Very handy if you want to match multiple items.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
var a = ["foo","fool","cool","god","acl"];
var startsWith = 'c';

a.filter(function (value) {
    return value && value.length > 0 && value[0] == startsWith;
});

// yields: ["cool"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = ["foo","fool","cool","god","acl"];
var Character="f";
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    if(a[i].indexOf(Character)!=-1){

        document.write(a[i]+"<br/>");
    }
 }
```